# Force the web browser to request authentification when downloading a file located outside the webserver

Tags: networking, browser, download, drive, identification

I have a website, a kind on intranet one  (written in PHP & running on IIS)

Many hyperlinks point to PDF files which are not on the webserver, but on an other network drive. (don't ask me why ! :)

If the client has already (previsouly) logged to this network drive, download will proceed when client clicks the link.
If the client has not yet logged to the network drive, the download will fails ("Internet Explorer cannot display this page").

To download files from this website, clients thus have to open from Windows (i.e. 'my computer') this drive (all users have mapped this drive). Windows will then request authentification.

Is there a way to request the browser (Internet explorer in my case) to force the authentification request for this drive?

One way would be to store these indentifications data on Windows, but that is not what I want.
Is there other way ?

Thanks to everybody who would take time to bring an answer.

edit: it does not work only for clients who do not belong to the domain. But there are some in this case.